# No native library for SQLite JDBC in Windows

Tags: java, windows, sqlite, jdbc

The problem is that JDBC won't connect to the database saying that there is no native SQLite library.

Problem method:

```
public static void connect() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + $appRoot + "\\data\\db\\sqlite\\users.sqlite");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
    }
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error opening connection
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:239)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:61)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:28)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:21)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:115)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:90)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
   ...
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No native library found for os.name=Windows, os.arch=x86_64, paths=[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;E:\Program Files\gcc\bin;E:\Program Files\gcc\libexec\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.3.0;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;E:\Program Files\Maven\bin;E:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm;E:\Program Files\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.3\bin;E:\Program Files\WebStorm 2020.1\bin;C:\Gradle\gradle-6.7.1\bin;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;.]
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:367)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.initialize(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:67)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.load(NativeDB.java:63)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:235)
    ... 10 more
```

Platform: `win x86-x64`

Comment: Please show how you run your application. Did you by any chance create a fat-jar instead of having the sqlite-jdbc.jar on the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your build file

```
kapt "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0"
```

Check out [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-12342) thread for details.