# Android Studio Arctic Fox : after update gradle error

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.MavenPomMetaInfoProvider'.

apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

The following were changes done in app after gradle update in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
-distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
+distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

and under build.gradle

```
-        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
+        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'

-        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
+        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.2'
```

Adding app level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.6'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086806/android-studio-failed-to-apply-plugin-id-com-android-application

Comment: looks there is a incompatibility versions

Comment: The plugin android-maven-gradle-plugin seems to be deprecated since the android-gradle-plugin now supports publishing to maven. See if this article helps? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin

I don't think I will be able to help further unless you can share some more details on gradle config code, or how your maven publishing is configured, or a reproducible build.

Comment: I had similar build issue while working in the arctic fox. I am not sure but this might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68664590/6390459

Comment: what version of java you are using

Comment: compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = "8"
        sourceCompatibility = "8"
    }

Comment: Can I see both module and app build.gradle because the error might be in one of those.

Comment: What is your purpose of using com.github.dcendents.android-maven? This is a deprecated library.

Comment: it was there by default, I am not sure how it got added in the first place. but it became an issue after I got the upgrade to arctic fox gradle 7.0.0

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/adding?authuser=1#setup

Answer (score 2):

After I made the upgrade to Artic Fox, I had to set the proper SDK for gradle in settings for things to work. By default after the update, it was still using Java 1.8, although JAVA_HOME was set properly and I had issues when applying `com.android.application` plugin.

Also, I removed all the JVM target params from gradle files

[image: Gradle Settings]

Comment: thanks for your answer. tried this solution. did not work.

Comment: Installing JDK 11 and then setting `JAVA_HOME` to this JDK worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Can you switch your,

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
```

to,

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0' // or 4.2.2
```

According to [Gradle Plugin Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?hl=BG) I cannot see 7.0.0 listed there.

Comment: yes, as per the question. reverting it back always works. it is an attempt to upgrade to gradle 7.0.0, which is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The `maven` plugin hase been removed from `Gradle` 7 . Check the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#removal_of_the_legacy_maven_plugin) .
Now you should use `maven-publish` plugin , to activate it add

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
}
```

or

`apply plugin: 'maven-publish'`

in your build script, instead using `apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'`

Otherwise you have to roll back to older `Gradle` version.

Comment: thanks for your answer. tried this solution. did not work.

Comment: would you please share your build.gradle of Project and app level?

Comment: i found something similar, but not able to understand it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599438/gradle-7-and-jitpack-io-runs-into-error-during-publish

Comment: yes, added now build.gradle at app level.

Comment: did you added/applied  `plugin: 'maven-publish'` at the end of this gradle? then you can see publishing tasks under Gradle  Task at the top of right corner of the IDE.

Comment: documentation for link you shared https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven

Comment: yes. i replaced  apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' with apply plugin: 'maven-publish' under build.gradle(app). stil issue persists.

Comment: would you please attach your another build.gradle ?

Comment: Check `settings.gradle` , is there  `plugins{}` block with id ?